# Removing a NSData stored in CoreData

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsdata

I saved a NSData (of UIImage) in an attribute of CoreData.
There are still some other attributes under the same entity.
How can I remove just the NSData stored, but not removing the whole NSManagedObject?
I tried overwriting it to nil, but the size of DB did not change at all, which means the NSData is not removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the amount of space used to store some value for that attribute is still there, but it does not mean that you did not successfully obliterate the value. Did you use `[managedObjectContext save:&error]` after writing to the value? If so and it reported no error then the value is gone.

(Does the size of the store really increase when you set an attribute? I expect it would when you add an entity but not just for setting an attribute.)

Comment: For example, I have an entity "Image" and an attribute "data" in it. At first, I save the NSData directly into "data". Then I want to delete that NSData that I saved. And the way that I was doing with it is, setting image.data = nil. The [managedObjectContext save:&error] seems like did not return any error. But as I check to see the size of the file "coredata.SQLlite", it remains the same size. That is why I thought the NSData was not removed from the store. And as entity "Image" increases (which means I saved another image), the size of the file "coredata.SQLlite" did increase too.

Comment: I guess I would hope for some real Core Data expert to explain what is going on, but in the absence of that I expect that it's an optimisation of sorts - the storage is not being reclaimed because it doesn't need to be immediately. Perhaps it would be reused when next the store needs to grow or will be resized during some other operation that requires changing the size of the store.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Adam. I still dont know the answer yet. However, I was doing a migration to move all the NSData in my DB to path. That might kinda solve the problem abit, but still remain mystery ^^

Answer (score 0):

if you are using tableview to display your CoreData and edit current indexPath in an new VC, try YOURCOREDATA.setNilValueForKey("YOUR IMAGE KEY"). 
i'm just a newbee of iOS dev but it works fine to me at least.